# Python: add up every 3 rows in a dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe

I have a dataframe named df like this:

```
index   a   b   c   d   e   f   g 
1       1   2   3   4   5   6   7   
2       2   3   4   5   6   7   8   
3       3   4   5   6   7   8   9   
4       4   5   6   7   8   9   0  
5       5   6   7   8   9   0   1   
6       6   7   8   9   0   1   2   
7       7   8   9   0   1   2   3   
8       8   9   0   1   2   3   4
```

I am trying to keep first 2 rows and combine every 3 rows after 2nd row and add up values.
The result should be like this:

```
Index   a   b   c   d   e   f   g
1       1   2   3   4   5   6   7
2       2   3   4   5   6   7   8
3       12  15  18  21  24  17  10
4       21  24  17  10  3   6   9
```

For example, col['a'],index 3 = 12, which is 3+4+5

I can only add them one row at a time. is there any iterate clean way to add them up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `.rolling()` and selecting every third row:

```
df1 = df[:2]
df1 = df1.append(df[2:].rolling(3).sum().dropna()[::3]).reset_index(drop=True)

# increase index by 1
df1.set_index(np.arange(len(df1))+1)

    a       b       c       d       e       f       g
1   1.0     2.0     3.0     4.0     5.0     6.0     7.0
2   2.0     3.0     4.0     5.0     6.0     7.0     8.0
3   12.0    15.0    18.0    21.0    24.0    17.0    10.0
4   21.0    24.0    17.0    10.0    3.0     6.0     9.0
```